# The file is not part of the project or its build action property is not set to resource

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml

Here's a screenshot:[image]

How can I display the 'no.png' image? It seems changing it to Resource worked.

How can I change the image in my code-behind c# file?

```
imgStatus.Source = new ur???
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format like this Source="/YourProjectName;component/images/yes.png"
The images folder should be resided in your project root directory.
The Visual Studio can automatically generate the path in the image control's property setting panel.